# How to create UINavigationBar drop shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Would like to know create drop shadow for UINavigationbar. I tried to create custom navigation bar background with drop shadow, but the drop shadow cover the background view.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"titleBar.png"] retain];;
   [image drawInRect:rect];
   [image release];
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
   CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,50);
   return newSize;
}
@end

I also tried on following solution: http://www.travisboudreaux.com/adding-a-drop-shadow-to-a-uinavigationbar: 

@interface UINavigationBar (dropshadow)

-(void) applyDefaultStyle;

@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (dropshadow)

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow{
   [self applyDefaultStyle];
}

- (void)applyDefaultStyle {
  // add the drop shadow
  self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
  self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0);
  self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
}
@end
```

It shows drop shadow for my navigationbar button, but no the navigation bar itself.

**Final Solution:**
Here's how I create drop shadow for UINavigationBar. Big thanks for MusiGenesis for pointing out the missing link of my code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

-(void) applyDefaultStyle;

@end

//Override For Custom Navigation Bar
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"titleBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];   
}

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];
    [self applyDefaultStyle];
}

- (void)applyDefaultStyle {
    // add the drop shadow
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}

@end
```

** Remember to import quartzcore or it will throw error.

Comment: Quick FYI, I think calling `[super willMoveToWindow:..]` is redundant in a category

Comment: Ah..yes it is. Have modified it. Thanks.

Comment: Could optimise a bit more adding:

self.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.layer.bounds] CGPath];

as seen on http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/on-the-importance-of-setting-shadowpath/

Comment: The above code adds shadow to each and every navigationbar in my app.how to control this?I need shadow only on one or two  viewControllers only.Please help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In `applyDefaultStyle`, try adding this line:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

The default value for this property is `YES`, which means that even though the shadow is rendered, it won't be rendered outside the bounds of the view, which means effectively that you don't see it at all.

If you're animating this view in any way, you should also add this line:

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

... unless you want the animation to be slow and jerky.

Comment: Thanks bro! You have save me lots of time before dwelling in drawing the shadow with quartz. I didn't expect it to be that easy.

Comment: I'm a big fan of drop shadows, and I went through the same thing of wondering why my shadows never showed up.

Answer (score 43):

If you apply a drop shadow to a `UINavigationBar`, the shadow is clipped at below the corners:

[image: clipped shadow]

This is just how shadows behave on rectangles. I usually create a path for the shadow that's a bit wider than the actual nav bar, which creates an effect that is more like what you'd generally expect:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (DropShadow)

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,4);
    CGRect shadowPath = CGRectMake(self.layer.bounds.origin.x - 10, self.layer.bounds.size.height - 6, self.layer.bounds.size.width + 20, 5);
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowPath].CGPath;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```

[image: better]

Comment: would you suggest this over adding a "shadow"-png as the sub view. I'm asking from the performance perspective

Comment: If you set `shouldRasterize = YES`, I don't think there's any discernible performance difference. This approach also works well with rotation, though I suppose the imageView approach would work if you use a wider CGRect.

Comment: Actually, this works if you present your UINavigationBar in portrait OR in landscape, but not if you rotate your device while UINavigationBar is presented. Putting this code in drawRect: will work if rotated too.

Answer (score 9):

Since iOS 6.0, UINavigationBar has a property shadowImage:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *shadowImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

which of course greatly simplifies this very common task :D

Answer (score -1):

I stick the shadow drawing code into a function to keep loadView clean. You could pass in the object you want to draw the shadow on if you wanted all your shadows consistent.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self drawShadow];
}


- (void)drawShadow
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
}
```