# iOS - Display UINavigationBar drop shadow behind UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have followed the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940076/how-to-create-uinavigationbar-drop-shadow) to create a drop shadow for my UINavigationBar. However, the shadow is above the UITableCell that is directly below the bar ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAgzg.png)). How would I go about making the cell cover up the shadow, so that the shadow of the bar is only visible if you scroll up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to create a background image using Photoshop (or a similar application) leaving **44px** (88px for the retina display) from the top and making the shadow start from there.

Then just use that as a `backgroundColor` of your window.

[image]

The NavBar in the image will be covered from the actual navigationBar and only the shadow will be visible (beneath the tableView as you asked.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to make the shadow only visible if scrolling up, but may be you can set UIScrollViewDelegate to the table view and deal with the event when the table view scrolling up and set shadow of navigation bar, remove shadow when scrolled to top.