# iOS 4.3 transparent png in status bar isn't transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm having some difficulty getting the transparent bits of my png image that I'm using to replace the default status bar to be rendered as transparent in iOS 4.3. At the moment they are coming up black.

Here is the code I'm using to draw my image:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (BackgroundImage)
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
    {
        UIImage *image = nil;

        switch(self.tag)
        {
            case HeaderBG_Logo:
                image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"top_bar_logo.png"];
                break;
            case HeaderBG_Plain:
                image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"top_bar.png"];
                break;
        }

        if(image != nil)
        {
            [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        }

    }
@end
```

Here is a side by side comparison of the same app running in the simulator in ios4.3 and ios5 (the image has a drop shadow as its bottom border):
[image: screenshot]

As an aside, the 4.3 background image doesn't seem to be rendered as tall as the 5.0 one either.

I've tried setting the `UINavigationBar` to opaque / setting its background color to `clearColor`. None of that worked. :(

Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem with the height not being equal has to do with the fact that on iOS 4 you code will daw you image in 44 height of the `UINavigationBar`. In iOS 5 it draws it outside of the bar's height.

Comment: Didn't even think of that - thanks for solving that little mystery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from [How to create UINavigationBar drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940076/how-to-create-uinavigationbar-drop-shadow) to add a shadow to the `UINavigationBar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint, for iOS 5 you could use the new `appreance` property to set the background image:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This will set the image for all `UINavigationBar`s in the app.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using that for iOS 5. I'm just struggling with iOS 4.3 :(

Comment: ah, sorry I just realized the opposite :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand if you are concerned by the status bar or by the navigationBar. According to you question it seems you are more concerned by the Navigation so here is a sample code that worked for me to add a background image for iOS5 and iOS4. It works with transparent png.

Just add this in the loadView method of your viewController:

```
#define kBackgroundImageTag 42

UINavigationBar *theNavigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *myBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

if([theNavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) //iOS5 stuff
{
     [theNavigationBar setBackgroundImage:myBackgroundImage forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
else if(![theNavigationBar viewWithTag:kBackgroundImageTag]) //iOS 4 stuff
{
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myBackgroundImage];
     imageView.tag = kBackgroundImageTag;
     [theNavigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks for this - i actually ended up taking a different route alltogether by adding a shadow to the ‘UINavgiationBar’ instead